# MultipartEntity and Json

Tags: java, android, json, upload, multipartentity

I want to send an image and a JsonObject to an PHP Server with MultipartEntity.
Here is my Code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlString);
File file = new File(imageend);
HttpResponse response = null;
MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
StringBody sb;

try {
    sb = new StringBody(json.toString());

    mpEntity.addPart("foto", cbFile);
    mpEntity.addPart("json", sb);
    httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
    response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
```

I can't read this in php because the format is like:

```
{\"test1\":\"Z\",\"test2\":\"1\"}
```

I'm not able to read this in php because of the backslashes. If I post json without image over httppost and bytearrayentity there aren't any backslashes and I have no problem.

Comment: how you are creating your `json` object?

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
      try {
       json.put("test1", test1.getText().toString());
       json.put("test2", test2.getText().toString());

Comment: Can you see what does `json.toString()` return? Does contain these backslashes?

Comment: may be you should specifcy and encoding in your stringbody ?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov: Great question. I tried to String test = json.toString(); and there are no backslashes! So the problem should be the StringBody! But how can I read out the StringBody? I toggled a breakpoint but I can't see it.

Comment: @njzk2 great idea how can I do this?

Comment: in the stringbody constructor if i recall

Comment: btw, i used this method (json + multipart), (not in php though), and it did work, so i know it is possible to have a proper result. can you post the request dump (except the image full binary part) ?

Comment: I'm a Newbie how can I do this? I have to go away for a few minutes, will answer immediately after coming back. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Now can you tell me how to post the request dump?

Answer (score 2):

Use following PHP:

```
string stripslashes ( string $str )
```

Comment: I tried this and it works, but if I want to upload an text with splashes in it it will delete them, right?

Comment: then use /\  and remove slash

Comment: if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function stripslashes_deep($value)
    {
        $value = is_array($value) ?
                    array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                    stripslashes($value);

        return $value;
    }

    $_POST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_POST);
    $_GET = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_GET);
    $_COOKIE = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_COOKIE);
    $_REQUEST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST);
}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just replace the `\"` by `\` using preg_replace on the PHP side

Comment: Ok that's a good idea. But isn't there any possibility to resolve it in Java that it doesn't set the splashes when creating StringBody?

Comment: We had recently the same problem on an old server machine. The server automatically inserted the backslashes. The PHP version installed was 5.3.6. We could verify that on PHP versions 5.3.10 and higher the backslashes disappeared. The exact reason for this behavior is still  unknown